# dynamically set multi-select element's size attribute to the number of options

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, resize

I have a dynamic multiple <select> that I need to resize to fit the amount of options. I'm using jQuery

**[HERES A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8ECUh/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is exactly what you've asked for:

```
$('select').attr('size', $('select option').length);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resize using the CSS option, e.g.:

```
`$('select').attr('size', 20);`
```

Where 20 is the number of elements.

Comment: How does this work with a dynamic number of `<option>` elements?

Comment: let's say each element takes 5 px. then you can change 400px to nrOfElements * 5 + 'px'

Comment: Let's say the user has set their browser's font to 24pt Comic Sans Bold. Using pixel sizes for this isn't entirely viable.

Comment: Well you could have forced whatever font and font-size you wanted. but I found a better way for this. Will edit my response

Comment: That still doesn't address the OP's specific case of having a dynamic number of elements.

Comment: @drudge: Use a variable or access the element dynamically, as you're doing in your solution.  I think the OP's question is more about JQuery access functions than it is about how to use variables.